# Using pyodbc in Azure Data Studio: no drivers

Tags: python, azure, pyodbc

I'm working in Azure Data Studio for the first time.  I have successfully installed 'python'(3.7) and 'pyodbc' (if I try to reinstall I get the message that the dependency is already satisfied).  I have also tried running the same script locally on macOS with the same result: empty list.  I was expecting a list of the drivers.  Any ideas as to what might be happening?

UPDATE/SOLUTION:
I learned that for MacOS drivers will be in Library/ODBC.  If that is empty or non-existent then you have have no drivers for pyodbc to use.
If you have no driver then you get it from somewhere so in my case [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

[image]

Comment: is it linux, mac or windows platform?

Comment: The code is fine, do you have any drivers on your machine?

Comment: local was on a macOS platform

Comment: @TonyJu I know for certain I have postgres drivers, but I thought pyodbc came with drivers.  If not, how do I determine what drivers I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the solution visible to others, thanks @MikeB2019x for sharing the solution.

> For **MacOS**, drivers will be in Library/OBDC. If that is empty or
>   non-existent then you have have no drivers for pyodbc to use. If you
>   have no driver then you get it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).